# How to add a value per second to cell (google sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

for example i have this table

| a | b ( value per second ) | c (final result) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.5 | 25 |

i want to add cell b1 to c1 every second or minute ( both type will be perfect )
so c1 should be 12.5 , 25 , 37.5 , 50 , etc ... every second or minute
i tried to search it , i couldn't find something useful
is there any formula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: `c1 = b1 +12.5` then copy c1 and paste in d1, e1, f1  .. right?

Comment: Would this help? https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/time-triggers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about a formula that can do this, but I know this can be done fairly easily in Apps Script, so that's what I've done.

## Script

All you'll have to do yourself is fill out the name of the sheet you want to work on in the code, which I've commented in the code itself for you.

It'll then grab all needed data and run through it, adding the B column to the C column all the way down.

```js
function adding() {
  // variables
  const sheetName = 'name of sheet';

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // goes from B2 to the last row that has any input and is 2 columns wide
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  
  let counter = 2;
  for (const row of range) {
  sheet.getRange(`C${counter}`).setValue(row[0] + row[1]);
  counter++;
  }

}
```

## Trigger

In order to make this work every minute (second based isn't possible with triggers) you'll have to setup a trigger event.

### How to get to triggers

On the left hand side in the script editor you can select Triggers with the little clock icon. This will take you to the triggers page where you can create a new one in the bottom right.
[image]

### Setup trigger

Make sure to select the right function and to change the `event source` to time-driven. Now you chose how often you want it to run, which can be once a minute.
[image]

Comment: is that very useful and is that exactly what i want, just a small problem here , i have a lot of rows : i want to do this calculation for all of B column to C column , i tried to change value in script to this : function adding() {
  // variables
  const sheetName = 'cal1';

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const addNumber = sheet.getRange('b2:b100').getValue();
  const numberToAddTo = sheet.getRange('c2:c100').getValue();
  const newNumber = numberToAddTo + addNumber;
  sheet.getRange('c2:c100').setValue(newNumber);
}

Comment: I edited the original post to work on a range instead of a singular row @Masoudhoseinpour

Comment: thank you very very much , you saved me :)